# Firebase, scheduled function, how to pass param/get context of local run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am testing my scheduled function via this approach:

```
   firebase functions:shell  
   firebase> RUN_NAME_OF_THE_FUCTION()
```

In this function, I am verifying if an action should be run, and if it should, I am sending emails. The problem - I can't differentiate between the test and prod environment as I do not know how to:

1. Pass an argument to the scheduled function
2. Understand the context of me running a local function.

Is there a way for me to somehow identify that the scheduled function was run manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pass an argument to the scheduled function

Scheduled functions don't accept custom arguments, so it doesn't really make sense to pass one.  They receive a context, and that's all it should expect.

> Understand the context of me running a local function.

You can simply set an environment variable on your development machine prior to executing the function.  Check this variable at the time of execution to determine that it's being tested, as opposed to invoked on a schedule.

You can also use environment variables to effectively "pass" data to the function for the purpose of development, if that helps you.

Comment: Brilliant - You, kind sir, saved me a lot of struggle ;) 
My solution so far: 
> process.env.TEST = true; 
within the code I am verifying if process.env.TEST exist and is equal to true. 

Thank you!